# I'm making an application in Flutter but the items don't fit on the screen

Tags: android, flutter, dart, listview, android-listview

I'm making an application in Flutter but the items don't fit on the screen, when I want to use ListView the position of the items get mixed up and it looks terrible, how can I edit these codes?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  late double screenWidth;
  late double screenHeight;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            colors: [
              Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1.0),
              Color.fromRGBO(69, 60, 60, 1.0),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            // Sol üst köşe - Logo
            Positioned(
              top: screenHeight * 0.04,
              left: screenWidth * 0.05,
              child: Container(
                width: screenWidth * 0.1,
                height: screenHeight * 0.1,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/logo.png'), // Logo resminin yolu
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            // Sağ üst köşe - Arama Butonu
            Positioned(
              top: screenHeight * 0.05,
              right: screenWidth * 0.03,
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                color: Colors.white,
                iconSize: screenWidth * 0.06,
                onPressed: () {
                  // Arama butonuna tıklandığında yapılacak işlemler
                },
              ),
            ),
            // Alt kenar - Butonlar
            Positioned(
              top: screenHeight * 0.14,
              left: screenWidth * 0.05,
              right: screenWidth * 0.4,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Expanded(child: buildButton("Kitaplar")),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10.0,
                  ),
                  Expanded(child: buildButton("Makaleler")),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10.0,
                  ),
                  Expanded(child: buildButton("Kategoriler")),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            // Resmin üzerindeki butonlar
            Center(
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: screenWidth * 0.8,
                    height: screenHeight * 0.6, // Resmin yüksekliği
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(screenWidth * 0.04),
                      border:
                          Border.all(color: Color.fromRGBO(69, 60, 60, 1.0)),
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image:
                            AssetImage('assets/pics/beyond good and evil.jpg'),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // Resmin üzerindeki butonlar
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: screenHeight * 0.02,
                    left: screenWidth * 0.10,
                    child: Container(
                      height: screenHeight * 0.05,
                      width: screenWidth * 0.25,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.circular(screenWidth * 0.02),
                          color: Colors.white),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.visibility),
                            iconSize: screenWidth * 0.04,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            onPressed: () {},
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Oku',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontSize: screenWidth * 0.04),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10.0,
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: screenHeight * 0.02,
                    left: screenWidth * 0.37,
                    child: Container(
                      height: screenHeight * 0.05,
                      width: screenWidth * 0.33,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.circular(screenWidth * 0.02),
                          color: Colors.white),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                            iconSize: screenWidth * 0.05,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            onPressed: () {},
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Listem',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontSize: screenWidth * 0.04),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            // Beyaz kutuların listesi
            Positioned(
              bottom: screenHeight * 0.2 / 9,
              left: screenWidth * 0.05,
              right: screenWidth * 0.05,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Yeni Kitaplar:',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: screenWidth * 0.04,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                  Container(
                    height: screenHeight * 0.2,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemCount: 10,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Container(
                          width: screenWidth * 0.20, // Kutu uzunluğu
                          height: screenHeight * 0.1,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.circular(12.0), // Kutu kalınlığı
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildButton(String text) {
    return Container(
      width: screenWidth * 0.2,
      height: screenHeight * 0.04,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.black,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(screenWidth * 0.05),
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: screenWidth * 0.020,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}
```

I tried various listview methods, I tried column but I couldn't get any result, I think I need to remove it from the stack tag but in this case I can't get the design I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys i am solved this problem!!!

Result: Remove stack and again edit is codes (widgets and item positions) and you do should wrap body with singlechildscrollview and finsh!!!